# Reducing Babylon CDN load size to increase site loading side speed

Tags: babylonjs

I am using Babylon CDN for my 360 images on my Shopify site. When I get the GTMatrix site speed report, Babylon CDN has HIGH flag that is showing slows the website load speed. How can I reduce Babylon CDN load size to increase site speed?
Alternatively, how can I prevent it load and I want to render it when I click the button?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The technique you're describing is called lazy loading. Here's a [shopify blog](https://www.shopify.com.au/partners/blog/lazy-loading) describing it.

You may be able to achieve this by using the [async](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) script tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/babylon.js" async></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of improvements that can be done to increase images load speed

1. Compress images (https://tinypng.com/)
2. Use correct size resolution
3. Convert images to modern webp format to reduce file size
4. Use images lazy load (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)